# Does an XPath change if the content inside it changes?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, bots

Does the Xpath change if the content inside the XPath changes?

I.e. the website changes the text in the XPath from 'supports' to 'support'. Would the XPath change even if the text change or will it stay the same?

Comment: What do you mean by `XPath changes`?

Comment: The XPath code in inspect element. When you right click on an element and copy the XCode, would it change if the content changes? Does that make more sense or no?

Comment: XPath is NOT a code in web element. XPath is a syntax to locate web element on the page according to it attributes

Comment: Yes, and does it change if I edit the name of a button? So keep the CSS but just change the text inside the button from 'Supports' to 'Support'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is a syntax to locate element on the page based on it attributes like tag name, class name, id, href etc values.
Also it can be located relatively to other elements.
So, if you are locating the element based on it's tag name and class name (for example) and you changing the element text content this will not affect selecting this element with previously created XPath locator.
However if you are locating the element based on it's text content and you changing that text - that XPath locator will obviously not find that element no more since now no more presented element with the old text on this web page.

Answer (score 1):

You make the common mistake of thinking that every element has "an XPath". Not so - there are any number of XPath expressions that will select a particular element. Just as you might be John Smith, Mary Smith's husband, Pete Smith's second son, Susan Smith's dad, or the guy wearing red trainers, so elements can be identified in XPath by any number of their distinguishing characteristics: and any particular XPath expression will continue to select that element so long as those characteristics don't change.

Answer (score 1):

See, it's bad practice to have `xpath` with `harcoded` text, cause if you are viewing website in `English` then `xpath` (let's say) `//div[text()='support']` represent at least one node in DOM, where as if same website in other countries (let's say German ) have some different text for support, right ? so your automation scripts will fail due to not having a common xpath locator.

Having said that, `xpath` is least preferable over `ID`, `class name`, `tag name`, `css selector`, `link text`, `partial link text`, and if none of them are working obviously you will have to use `xpath`. Also xpath comes handy if you wanna **move upward** in DOM.